# Facebook Graph API: OAuthException, code: 1500, message: (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

My ruby codes was running OK but now I just found random exceptions thrown. I traced down and it seems like a FB bug.
Look below. If I provide the valid URL to the link parameter when creating a page post, there's exception. 
If I change it to other random stuff then it's OK.
Then after a few other tries if I come back to try the same URL it's OK this time.

--

```
[26] pry(FB::Post)> attrs[:link] = 'http://www.groupon.com/deals/new-health-centers'
=> "http://www.groupon.com/deals/new-health-centers"

[27] pry(FB::Post)> graph_post.put_connections(FB.config.page_id, 'feed', attrs)
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 1500, message: (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid [HTTP 400]
from /Users/wedeng/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/koala-1.6.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:470:in `block in graph_call'

[30] pry(FB::Post)> attrs[:link] = 'http://www.groupon.com/dealx/newshealthscentersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
=> "http://www.groupon.com/dealx/newshealthscentersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

[31] pry(FB::Post)> graph_post.put_connections(FB.config.page_id, 'feed', attrs)
=> {"id"=>"60004615820_10151782223830821"}
```

Comment: This bug is just random. This looks like the same bug [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573295/facebook-wall-post-error-oauthexception-1500-the-url-you-supplied-is-inva]here.

Comment: I built a script to remove all the ads/creativs/posts under my test campaign, and this issue is gone.
It seems this FB bug is triggered by something related to insufficient resources.